# Ridge regression and low R-squared

Tags: autocorrelation, goodness-of-fit, ridge-regression

I am currently working with a strongly balanced data set. I have 15 countries over the period 1990-2017. My dependent variable is CO2 emissions. My independent variables are GDP per capita, total population, petroleum products used and urban population as a % of total population. All variables are taken in log as I am following the STIRPAT framework.

I used the first difference correction method to correct for autocorrelation in my model. I then used the ridge regression model to get my coefficients. However, after using the first difference correction method the R-squared dropped from 90% to 17.25%. Should this be of major concern to me?

Screenshot of the output of ridge regression
[image]

Comment: $R^2$ on your training data or on some holdout data to which the model has not been exposed?

Comment: what do u mean by "found a high about of multicollinearity"

Comment: All your variables can be expected to show clear trends for most countries (except possibly % urban which might not change much for developed countries). So the difference between a model for data with trends and a model for differences is expected to be very substantial.

Comment: @NickCox so in cases where the independent variables have a clear trend (increasing or decreasing), Rsquared is less important? ,apologies if im misinterpreting your answer.

Comment: @Dave the R2 of my final model.

Comment: It's not a matter of being less or more important. If variables are trending upwards -- regardless of whether they are interlinked or the trend reflects something outside the system -- then $R^2$ is likely be  high.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with multicollinearity is just to be sparing with the number of predictors you throw into the model.